# Avoid show recent conversation list when back from ConversationActivity

Tags: android, applozic

After installing Applozic everything is correct and works very well, but when the user clicks back on the ConversationActivity, the list of their conversations is displayed. When the user presses back again, then the activity previous to the chat is shown.

In my case the list of conversations is not necessary. Is it possible to avoid this step? I have searched in JSON configuration file but I do not think any option solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to pass flag in intent **intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.TAKE_ORDER, true);** 
if this flag is true then list of conversations will be not show after back press when you launch chat with intent

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConversationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.TAKE_ORDER, true);//flag to disable list after back press  
            intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.USER_ID, "userId");
            intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.DISPLAY_NAME, "display name");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

First when go to ConvertionActivity that time you finish() previous activity so when you back the ConvertionActivity then your previous activity is not displayed.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(ChatListActivity.this,ConvertionActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but sorry if I did not explain well the problem. The activity I want to quit is the list of conversations that is shown when the user press back in the ConversationActivity. Example:   

myActivity --> ConversationActivity --> (when back) --> conversations of the user (this activity created by Applozic I want to not show) --> (when back) --> myActivity

Comment: I should have indicated that I am using the parameter USER_ID in the intent.